# I am trying to create a search query “How far my users are with respect to the current user who is online”. I have lat and Long values for all

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am using Firebase realtime database where the Nodes go a bit like this.
Company-> Users-> Registered Tutors ->All the data like longitude, latitude, name, dob, gender etc...
The idea behind it is, that when the user searches for the registered tutors, the latitude and longitude values of all registered tutors are retrieved, the latitude and longitude values of current user are also retrieved, and only the distance between them is shown in the search query.

I am using a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Sorry I am terrible with words, maybe the code and a few pictures would help.

This is my Activity (section of it)

```
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference allUsersDatabaseRef, currentUserRefLong, currentUserRef;
        allUsersDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("oxtuition").child("Users").child("Registered Tutors");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        currentUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("oxtuition").child("Users").child(currentUserID);

        SearchResultList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
        SearchResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        SearchResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String searchBoxInput = SearchInputText.getText().toString();
                SearchPeopleAndFriends(searchBoxInput);
            }
        });

    }

    private void SearchPeopleAndFriends(String searchBoxInput) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Searching....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Query searchPeopleAndFriendsQuery = allUsersDatabaseRef.orderByChild("fullname").startAt(searchBoxInput).endAt(searchBoxInput + "\uf8ff");
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsViewHolder>(FindFriends.class,
                R.layout.all_tutors_display_layout,
                FindFriendsViewHolder.class,
                searchPeopleAndFriendsQuery) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FindFriendsViewHolder findFriendsViewHolder, FindFriends model, int i) {
 findFriendsViewHolder.setLocation(model.getLocation());


            }
        };
        SearchResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    public static class FindFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public FindFriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }





      public void setLocation(String location) {
            TextView mylocation = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_how_far);
            mylocation.setText(location);



        }

    }
}
```

Now it's the problem page, the FindFriends.class where the constructor and the setters and getters are.

```
public class FindFriends
{

    public double longitude;
    public double latitude, location;
public FindFriends(){
}

    public FindFriends(String fullname, String profilimage, String subjects, String addresspostcode, String shortdescription, double longitude, double latitude) {
        this.longitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(longitude));
        this.latitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(latitude));
    }



    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude; //Longitude Getter
    }
    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude; //Longitude Setter
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude; //Latitude Setter
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude; //Latitude Getter
    }

    public String getLocation() {// Location getter doesn't exist in Firebase, it's calculated based upon the latitude and the longitude
        final double lon1 = this.longitude; 
        final double lat1 = this.latitude;

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String CurrentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("oxtuition").child("Users").child(CurrentUserID);

        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String lon2S = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                String lat2S = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();

//This is the mathematics behind calculating the distance between two latitude //and longitude values
                double lon2 = Double.valueOf(lon2S);
                double lat2 = Double.valueOf(lat2S);
                System.out.println("Print OK" + lon2 + lat2);

                double thetaLong = (lon2 - lon1)*Math.PI/180;
                double thetaLat = (lat2 - lat1)*Math.PI/180;
                double lat1Rad = lat1*Math.PI/180;
                double lat2Rad = lat2*Math.PI/180;
                double a = Math.sin(thetaLat/2)*Math.sin(thetaLat/2) + Math.cos(lat1Rad)*Math.cos(lat2Rad)*Math.sin(thetaLong/2)*Math.sin(thetaLong/2);
                double c = 2*Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
                double R = 6371;
                double d = (R*c);
                location = d; //the double location is the "DISTANCE" calculated //between two latitude and longitude points.
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed");
            }
        });
return Double.toString(location); 
//This returns the location calculated (hopefully, I feel like the problem is here)
    }
    public void setLocation() {
//don't really think this is even necessary.
    }



}
```

In the end I am returning a calculated location which is sent to the main activity. The problem is:

I am having problems reading the latitude and longitude values from the current user ID. I have tried using arbitary values by simply doing:

double lat1 = 1.234556;
double lon1 = 1.233467;

and i get the correct answer, but I can't do that when reading the current user ID location. Please help, I am really stuck! I get values of 0! That's it for all of them. I can give more information, don't really know what else to include in this thread really.

After this i am hoping I can arrange the results according to the distance. But that's a challenge for the future. I'll be happy if anyone has any inputs on that as well.

Thankyou in Advance!

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **more than 300 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I will make it more concise. You are right.

Comment: The main idea behind it is, when I press the search button. Its queries for the latitude and longitude of all users in that particular node. I receive the information, I then calculate the distance between the searched users and the current user. I only display the distance, how far they are. If you look at the FindFriends.class, under the getLocation method is where I think the problem is. I use an addEventListener to listen to the current users' latitude and longitude values.